# Flash like timeline in Canvas

Tags: html, flash, canvas

I am looking to create a animation movie, but instead of using Flash I am using HTML5 canvas.

In flash professional, there was a great timeline which allowed to create animations very easily. There were separate timelines for separate movieclips.

Is there any framework/library for working in a timeline like environment in HTML5 canvas?

If not, what is the best way to create animation movies in HTML5 canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you come from a Flash background, you should check out Grant Skinner’s EaselJS.**

EaselJS: http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS

It’s a canvas drawing library that gets its flavor from the Flash API—you get the stage and displayObjects you’re used to.  But it uses javascript and canvas to drive and display your animations.

If you have exsiting Flash assets, you can use his Zoe tool to convert your .swf into spritesheets that canvas can display.  I think I read somewhere that Grant Skinner and Adobe collaborated to make Zoe very accurate and stable—but don’t quote me on that!

I guess in theory you could:

- Do your future development in the fantastic Flash environment
- Use Zoe to convert the .swf into spritesheets
- Use a true canvas drawing library like EaselJS or KineticJS to control the sprites. (these libraries love spritesheets!)

Comment: Thanks, this seems worth trying. I will definitely try it within the course of the next week.

Answer (score 5):

Adobe have created a timeline based tool for DOM elements, but sadly it doesn't use the `canvas` element. It will use html that contains a `canvas` element though.

Its certainly work a look:

[Adobe edge animate](http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will have to do some research and think which technology to use. Thanks for the answer.